# Replace empty CSV value with NULL using sed

Tags: regex, bash, csv, sed

I have an CSV file which looks like this:

```
16949839,49.5474463,8.6692215,4,31336605,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,Schau- und Sichtungsgarten Hermannshof,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,attraction,,,,,,,,
17025149,49.5444114,8.6715051,2,670583,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,Voliere,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,attraction,,,,,,,,
24557757,50.0550103,11.8494971,5,8289559,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,1000-Meter-Stein,stone,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,attraction,,,,,,,,
25505794,50.0407824,11.8647266,5,7301040,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,Nußhardtstube,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,attraction,,,,,,,,
25631399,49.8270356,11.3753338,9,39834385,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,Sophienhöhle,cave_entrance,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,attraction,,,,,,,,
25932371,50.0527832,11.2319208,2,6747603,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,Gaaskerng,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,attraction,,,,,,,,
26309933,50.1225540,11.3759787,2,11211206,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,Staafelsn,cliff,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,attraction,,,,,,,,
26945605,49.7668812,11.4281553,7,39554170,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,Großes Hasenloch,cave_entrance,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,attraction,,,,,,,,
27133657,49.6351754,8.4938556,2,1638377,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,Schießbuckel,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,attraction,,,,,,,,
27133658,49.6339946,8.4853839,1,9218,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,Grillhütte,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,attraction,,,,,,,,
27153008,50.1229239,11.4117973,1,7826,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,Schwedenschanze,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,attraction,,,,,,,,
27374034,51.5455027,12.9933573,2,4177298,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,Sommer-Rodelbahn,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,attraction,,,,,,,,
27440567,50.7319121,7.0993708,10,11317500,,,,,,,,bus_station,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,Busbahnhof Bonn,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,attraction,,,,,,,,
27543115,51.8473136,12.2314568,8,19447141,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,building,,,,,,,,,,,Weißer Bogen,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,attraction,,,,,,,,
28788682,51.3384522,10.8616651,9,31145828,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,430,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,Freizeit und Erholungpark "Zum Possen",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,attraction,,,,,,,de:Possen (Sondershausen),
```

And I want to replace every empty CSV value with NULL. Therefor I'm using `sed`:

```
sed -r 's;^,|,$;NULL,;g
:l
s;,,;,NULL,;g
t l'
```

Which creates this:

```
16949839,49.5474463,8.6692215,4,31336605,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,Schau- und Sichtungsgarten Hermannshof,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,attraction,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,
17025149,49.5444114,8.6715051,2,670583,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,Voliere,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,attraction,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,
24557757,50.0550103,11.8494971,5,8289559,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,1000-Meter-Stein,stone,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,attraction,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,
25505794,50.0407824,11.8647266,5,7301040,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,Nußhardtstube,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,attraction,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,
25631399,49.8270356,11.3753338,9,39834385,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,Sophienhöhle,cave_entrance,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,attraction,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,
25932371,50.0527832,11.2319208,2,6747603,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,Gaaskerng,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,attraction,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,
26309933,50.1225540,11.3759787,2,11211206,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,Staafelsn,cliff,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,attraction,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,
26945605,49.7668812,11.4281553,7,39554170,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,Großes Hasenloch,cave_entrance,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,attraction,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,
27133657,49.6351754,8.4938556,2,1638377,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,Schießbuckel,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,attraction,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,
27133658,49.6339946,8.4853839,1,9218,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,Grillhütte,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,attraction,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,
27153008,50.1229239,11.4117973,1,7826,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,Schwedenschanze,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,attraction,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,
27374034,51.5455027,12.9933573,2,4177298,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,Sommer-Rodelbahn,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,attraction,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,
27440567,50.7319121,7.0993708,10,11317500,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,bus_station,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,Busbahnhof Bonn,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,attraction,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,
27543115,51.8473136,12.2314568,8,19447141,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,building,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,Weißer Bogen,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,attraction,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,
28788682,51.3384522,10.8616651,9,31145828,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,430,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,Freizeit und Erholungpark "Zum Possen",NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,attraction,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,de:Possen (Sondershausen)NULL,
```

Which is nearly what I want. The problem is that in the last line it adds `NULL` after `de:Possen (Sondershausen)` which is not what I want. Can someone tell me what is wrong with my `sed` command?

Comment: You have `s;^,|,$;NULL,;g` which will replace last `,` with `NULL,` which is the reason behind the issue you are facing.

Comment: The the solutions here may solve your test case, it suggested that you use a `perl` for the job. [\[ Text::CSV \]](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV) helps you handle complex CSV files and have a look at the test cases mentioned [\[ here \]](http://perlmaven.com/how-to-read-a-csv-file-using-perl)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use this `sed` to replace all `,,` with `NULL` or if `,` is at start, using a recursive label:

```
sed 's/^,/NULL,/; :a;s/,,/,NULL,/g;ta' file
```

This will not add `NULL` after trailing `,` in each line.

**Output:**

```
16949839,49.5474463,8.6692215,4,31336605,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,Schau- und Sichtungsgarten Hermannshof,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,attraction,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,
17025149,49.5444114,8.6715051,2,670583,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,Voliere,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,attraction,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,
24557757,50.0550103,11.8494971,5,8289559,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,1000-Meter-Stein,stone,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,attraction,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,
25505794,50.0407824,11.8647266,5,7301040,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,Nußhardtstube,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,attraction,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,
25631399,49.8270356,11.3753338,9,39834385,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,Sophienhöhle,cave_entrance,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,attraction,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,
25932371,50.0527832,11.2319208,2,6747603,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,Gaaskerng,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,attraction,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,
26309933,50.1225540,11.3759787,2,11211206,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,Staafelsn,cliff,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,attraction,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,
26945605,49.7668812,11.4281553,7,39554170,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,Großes Hasenloch,cave_entrance,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,attraction,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,
27133657,49.6351754,8.4938556,2,1638377,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,Schießbuckel,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,attraction,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,
27133658,49.6339946,8.4853839,1,9218,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,Grillhütte,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,attraction,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,
27153008,50.1229239,11.4117973,1,7826,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,Schwedenschanze,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,attraction,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,
27374034,51.5455027,12.9933573,2,4177298,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,Sommer-Rodelbahn,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,attraction,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,
27440567,50.7319121,7.0993708,10,11317500,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,bus_station,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,Busbahnhof Bonn,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,attraction,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,
27543115,51.8473136,12.2314568,8,19447141,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,building,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,Weißer Bogen,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,attraction,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,
28788682,51.3384522,10.8616651,9,31145828,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,430,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,Freizeit und Erholungpark "Zum Possen",NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,attraction,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,de:Possen (Sondershausen),
```

Answer (score 4):

I know the question wasn't tagged for `awk`, but for reference, here is a script doing the job:

```
awk -F, -v OFS=',' '{for(i=1;i<NF;i++) if(!$i)$i="NULL"}1' file
```

`-F, -v OFS=','` set the input and output delimeter to `,`, aka field separator.

`for(i=1;i<NF;i++)` is iterating through all fields except the last one.

`if(!$i)$i="NULL"` is setting the parameter to the string `"NULL"` if the parameter is empty.

The `1` at the end of the command is default action in `awk`: print the whole line.

Comment: Nice, this is the idiomatic way of doing it. Add a bit of explanation so that the answer will useful for potential askers in the longer run.

Comment: ok, didn't know if the answer would be well received since it doesn't strictly answer the `sed` question. comments added anyway...

Answer (score 0):

This `awk` script will also do the same job

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=",";OFS=","}
    {
      for(i=1;i<=(NF-1);i++)
      {
        if($i == ""){
         $i="NULL"
        }
      }
      print
    }' file
```

**Output**

```
16949839,49.5474463,8.6692215,4,31336605,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,Schau- und Sichtungsgarten Hermannshof,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,attraction,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,
17025149,49.5444114,8.6715051,2,670583,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,Voliere,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,attraction,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,
24557757,50.0550103,11.8494971,5,8289559,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,1000-Meter-Stein,stone,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,attraction,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,
25505794,50.0407824,11.8647266,5,7301040,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,Nußhardtstube,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,attraction,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,
25631399,49.8270356,11.3753338,9,39834385,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,Sophienhöhle,cave_entrance,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,attraction,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,
25932371,50.0527832,11.2319208,2,6747603,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,Gaaskerng,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,attraction,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,
26309933,50.1225540,11.3759787,2,11211206,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,Staafelsn,cliff,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,attraction,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,
26945605,49.7668812,11.4281553,7,39554170,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,Großes Hasenloch,cave_entrance,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,attraction,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,
27133657,49.6351754,8.4938556,2,1638377,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,Schießbuckel,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,attraction,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,
27133658,49.6339946,8.4853839,1,9218,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,Grillhütte,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,attraction,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,
27153008,50.1229239,11.4117973,1,7826,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,Schwedenschanze,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,attraction,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,
27374034,51.5455027,12.9933573,2,4177298,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,Sommer-Rodelbahn,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,attraction,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,
27440567,50.7319121,7.0993708,10,11317500,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,bus_station,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,Busbahnhof Bonn,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,attraction,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,
27543115,51.8473136,12.2314568,8,19447141,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,building,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,Weißer Bogen,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,attraction,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,
28788682,51.3384522,10.8616651,9,31145828,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,430,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,Freizeit und Erholungpark "Zum Possen",NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,attraction,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,de:Possen (Sondershausen),
```

**What happens here**

1. In the `for-loop`,we iterate through each field using the delimiter `,`
2. If any field is empty ie `if($i == "")` we assign the field to null
3. Since csv file ends with `,` we don't have to process the last record, so the for loop has `i<=(NF-1)`