# Unix. sed command. Replace a expression containing \n. Database migration from Sybase to MySQL. Windows-Unix plain text encoding

Tags: mysql, linux, unix, sed, file-encodings

I am migrating a database from Sybase to MySQL. For that, I am exporting the tables in .csv files and then loading them in the new tables in MySQL. 
When doing this, NULL values are converted to 0 in MySQL, so I need to edit the .csv files to find where there are no values and replace them with a NULL.

**Edited: I am exporting the .csv files from Sybase in Windows and working with them in Unix virtual machine.**

Null values may appear in middle columns:
3,,,4,5 --here it should look like 3,NULL, NULL,4,5
For doing this, I used successfully:

```
sed -i -e 's/,,/,NULL,/g' file_name.csv
```

(and run it two times).

The problem is when the NULL values are in the last column:
3,4,5, -- This should look like 3,4,5,NULL

In the text editor, I used find and replace successfully:
Find: ,\r\n
Replace: ,NULL\r\n

I want to automatize this from the Unix terminal, but it is not working. I tried:

```
sed -i -e 's/,\r\n/,NULL\r\n/' file_name.csv

sed -i -e 's/,\\r\\n/,NULL\\r\\n/' file_name.csv
```

Thank you!

Comment: Use `sed -i 's/,$/,NULL/' file_name.csv`. You may need to use `dos2unix` to convert lnebreaks to `\n` only.

Comment: This will work if the line starts, ends or contains a null:  `sed -i -e 's/^,/NULL,/' -e 's/,,/,NULL,/g' -e 's/,$/,NULL/' file_name.csv`

Comment: @kenlukas This emptied the file

Comment: @bertagp, what OS are you doing this on.  It worked as expected for me on CentOS7 and Ubuntu 16.04.  It didn't work on MacOS

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace empty CSV value with NULL using sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38205541/replace-empty-csv-value-with-null-using-sed)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, You were right with converting line breaks, as I was exporting the .csv files in Windows and then using them in the Unix virtual machine.

What I did exactly was:
     dos2unix -n file_in.csv file_out.csv
     sed -i 's/,$/,NULL/g' file_out.csv
.Thank you very much everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have Windows CRLF endings, you need to run `dos2unix` on the input files.

Then, all you need is to match `,` at the end of the lines only and replace them with a `,NULL`.

Here is the example:

```
dos2unix -n file_in.csv file_out.csv
sed -i 's/,$/,NULL/' file_out.csv
```

Note:

- `-i` will change the `file_out.csv`
- `,$` matches a `,` at the end of a line (`$`)
- Since `sed` operates on lines, you do not need `g` modifier, as there is only 1 end of a line on each line.

Answer (score 0):

Use twice

```
sed -ir 's/(^|,)(,|$)/\1null\2/g' file_name.csv
```

or one time

```
sed -ir 's/(^|,)(,|$)/\1null\2/g;s/(^|,)(,|$)/\1null\2/g' file_name.csv
```

or one time

```
sed -ir ':a;s/(^|,)(,|$)/\1null\2/g;ta' file_name.csv
```

This will change an empty line into `null`.